# How to force TypeScript exports to the end of the JS output?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I use a lot of export statements like the following, usually to cumulate a module's exports at the bottom of the file:

```
export { foo1 as bar1, foo2 as bar2, ... }
```

Lately I have learned that...

```
let foo : number = 0;
export { foo as bar }
```

...is not at all the same as...

```
let foo : number; foo = 0;
export { foo as bar }
```

...because the latter delivers undefined in **exports.bar**. This happens because the compiled JavaScript has the export statement of **exports.bar = foo** before the assignment. I find this hardly intuitive. I read over the TypeScript module pages, but I seem to miss the description of this behaviour. Is it there?

Is there a way to force the output's export statements to be at the bottom rather than right after declaration? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds more like a bug in TypeScript. For future reference, TypeScript 1.8 compiles the following code:

```
let foo : number; foo = 0;
export { foo as bar }
```

into this JavaScript:

```
"use strict";
var foo;
exports.bar = foo;
foo = 0;
```

I tried it with TypeScript 2.0 beta, and it seems like that fixes it:

```
"use strict";
var foo;
exports.bar = foo;
exports.bar = foo = 0;
```

Comment: You are right, and subsequently every access to an export (independent of scope or point of execution) will update the exports object when I use the latest nightly. The module page at TS should say: "Be a little careful when exporting anything other than a function literal or type when using stable TS".